# Python Selenium решение reCaptcha V2 Callback

Tags: python, selenium, recaptcha

Для решения капчи использую api ruCaptcha, все хорошо, разобрался как получать токен капчи, но не понимаю как вызвать Callback функцию чтобы капчу засчитало. Искал в DevTools > Console, Elements, даже в Sources пробовал найти(находил не те функции), делал дополнительную кнопку `<input type="submit">` возле капчи на странице, но ничего не работало.